# Avoiding cycles when finding shortest path between two nodes

Tags: graph-theory

I've written a method to find all possible paths between two nodes in a weighted graph. Edges can be either directed or undirected. On the most part, the algorithm below is working and retrieving the paths like I expect it to.

However, when there's an undirected edge between Node A and B, it cycles back from B to A and includes that in the list of paths. I've typed it up as pseudocode because this is an assignment and I don't want my code on the internet:

```
Function(findPaths)
{
    currPaths -> LinkedList
    currPath -> add(StartingNode) 
    findPathsRecurs(StartNode, FinishNode, currPaths)
}

Function(findPathsRecurse)
{
    storePaths -> LinkedList
    for(All adjacent nodes V to StartNode)
    {
        if(V->visited)
        {
             if(V = FinishNode)
             {
                  currPath -> add(V)
                  storePaths -> add(currPath)
                  currPath -> remove(V)
             }
        }
    }
    for(All adjacent nodes V2 to StartNode)
    {
         if(V2->not visited OR V2->not = FinishNode)
         {
              currPaths->add(V2)
              v2->visit

              findAllPathsRecurs(v2, FinishNode, currPaths)
              currPaths->removeFromBack
              v2->unvisit
         }
    }
}
```

Expected output from some Node A to Node D:

```
Path 1: A->B->C->D
Path 2: A->B->D
```

Actual output for some Node A to Node D:

```
Path 1: A->B->C->D
Path 2: A->B->D
Path 3: A->B->A->C->D
```

If I mark the node as visited in the first for loop, and then unvisited before that loop ends, nothing changes which is to be expected. If I just mark it as visited without unvisiting it (in the first for loop), then the code only stores one path, which also makes sense.

Just having trouble working my way around this and any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter out any path that visits the same node twice.

Comment: That's definitely doable, but would it be efficient/good coding practice? Especially with a large number of Vertices/Edges, there could be 100s of different paths if I don't account for cycles, and then I'd have to have separate code to filter them out.

Comment: The filter is trivial to code.  Try it and see if the performance is acceptable.  If not, then you can spend time and effort seeking a more efficient algorithm.  If acceptable, then you are done already.

Comment: My bad, I interpreted your comment in a very specific way - I was going to store all paths, then write another method to go through all of them, check for duplicates in those paths and remove those. But, I've managed to get it working by just simply checking if my currentPath already has that Vertex. Ty!